# Select statement in hive return some columns with null value

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, nonetype, hive-query

I have seen this type of questions were asked many times, but those solutions not worked for me. I created a external hive table, since i had the data is from map-only job output. Then, by load command i given the path for the specific file. It showed ok. But when i give `select * from table` command it returns some column with null values. Each command i have executed is in the error pic.

My delimiter in file is `||`, so i mentioned the same in create table command too.

Here is my input file pic [file pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3WQ5.png).  And here is the [error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdfDY.png)
. I have also tried a normal table instead of external table. That too showed the same error. I also tried by mentioning delimiter as `//||` and also `\|\|`. But none worked.

Comment: Is it working as expected when the delimiter is a single character?

Comment: Yeah!! After posting this i tried changing the delimiter, it works. But i dont know whats the problem with this `||`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you are facing is related to multiple characters as FIELD delimiter.

According to documentation FIELD delimiter should be a `CHAR`

```
row_format
  : DELIMITED [FIELDS TERMINATED BY char [ESCAPED BY char]] [COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY char]
        [MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY char] [LINES TERMINATED BY char]
        [NULL DEFINED AS char]   -- (Note: Available in Hive 0.13 and later)
```

You need to change your data to have only single char field delimiter.

If you can not do that then the other approach is to use stage table with single field. Load your data to that table and then in your actual target table, split the column in stage table by `||` delimiter and then insert. You need to make sure that field counts are consistent in the data otherwise your final output will be off.

Reference:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableCreate/Drop/TruncateTable